# React - Render Key Press Event

Tags: reactjs

I cannot seem to find a fitting example anywhere online. I have little experience with javaScript and React, and my issue might be trivial. The keypress event function works fine if run it by itself. However, if I try to implement it into the class app, and call the function from the render section I get this error: [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6empv.png). Any ideas? Thanks in advance. I have added the code.

```js
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import './App.css';
import Spotify from 'spotify-web-api-js';

const spotifyWebApi = new Spotify();

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    const params = this.getHashParams();
    

    this.state = {
      loggedIn: params.access_token ? true : false,
      nowPlaying: {
        name: 'Not Checked',
        image: '',
        device: '',
        user_id: '',
        playlists: []
      }
    }
    if (params.access_token){
      spotifyWebApi.setAccessToken(params.access_token)
    }
    
  };

  
  useKeyPress(targetKey) {
    const [keyPressed, setKeyPressed] = useState();
  
    // Når du trykker på knappen - sætter vi keyPressed til true for at vise resultatet.
    function downHandler({ key }) {
      if (key === targetKey) {
        this.setKeyPressed(true);
      }
    }
  
    // Når du releaser knappen - sætter vi keyPressed til false for at fjerne resultatet igen.
    const upHandler = ({ key }) => {
      if (key === targetKey) {
        this.setKeyPressed(false);
      }
    };
  
    useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener('keydown', downHandler);
      window.addEventListener('keyup', upHandler);
      // Det er altid "pænt" at ryde op efter sig selv, så vi fjerner eventListeners i return metoden
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('keydown', downHandler);
        window.removeEventListener('keyup', upHandler);
      };
    }, []);
  
    return this.keyPressed;
  }


  Fapp() {
    const aPressed = this.useKeyPress('a');
    const sPressed = this.useKeyPress('s');
    const dPressed = this.useKeyPress('d');
    const fPressed = this.useKeyPress('f');
  
    return (
      <div>
        { aPressed ? 'a' : 'not a'}
      </div>
    );
  }

  getHashParams() {
    var hashParams = {};
    var e, r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g,
        q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    while ( e = r.exec(q)) {
       hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
    }
    return hashParams;
  }


  getNowPlaying(){
    spotifyWebApi.getMyCurrentPlaybackState()
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          nowPlaying: {
            name: response.item.name,
            image: response.item.album.images[0].url
          }
        }
        )
      })
  }

 

  handleKeyDown(event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 13) { 
        console.log('Enter key pressed')
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <a href='http://localhost:8888'>
          <button>Login with Spotify</button>
        </a>

        <div> Now Playing: { this.state.nowPlaying.name } </div>
        <div> user: { this.state.nowPlaying.user_id } </div>

        <div>
          <img src={ this.state.nowPlaying.image } style={{width: 100}}/>
        </div>

        <button onClick={() => this.getNowPlaying()}>
          Check Now Playing
        </button>


      </div>
    );
  };
}

export default App;
```

Comment: React hooks can ***only*** be used in functional components. Either convert `App` to be a functional component, or convert the hooks to the equivalent component lifecycle functions, i.e. `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for the answer :) I will look into the functions you mention and revise the syntax.

Comment: Welcome... if/when you revise your code and still have any issue(s), please update question with new details.